# How to send a value with route params in another screen using Formik in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, parameters, formik

I need to send the phone value to the other screen where Im navigating. Im using Formik library for validation, here is my code

```
const phoneRegExp = /^((\\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \\-]*)|(\\([0-9]{2,3}\\)[ \\-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \\-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \\-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/;
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  phone: Yup.string()
    .label("Phone")
    .required("Ju lutem shkruani numrin")
    .matches(phoneRegExp, "Numri i telefonit nuk është valid")
    .min(6, "Numri duhet të jetë min 6 karaktere")
    .max(15, "Numri duhet të jetë max 15 karaktere"),
});

export default function ChangePassword({ navigation }) {
  const LoginAuthorization = async (value) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${apiURL}/recovery/send-reset-phone`, {
        phone: "+383" + value.phone,
        client: "HajdeApp",
      });
      navigation.navigate("CodeVerification");
    } catch (err) {
      Alert.alert("Mesazhi", err.response.data.message, [
        { text: "Në rregull" },
      ]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={global.container}>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          phone: "",
        }}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          LoginAuthorization(values);
        }}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
      >
        {({
          handleChange,
          values,
          handleSubmit,
          errors,
          isValid,
          isSubmitting,
          touched,
          handleBlur,
        }) => (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <BackButton onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Login")} />
            <Text style={global.titleText}>Shkruani numrin e telefonit</Text>
            <Text style={global.inputTitle}>Telefoni</Text>
            <View style={global.inputContainer}>
              <View style={global.prefixContainer}>
                <Text style={global.prefixText}>+355</Text>
              </View>
              <TextInput
                name="Phone"
                label="Phone"
                value={values.phone}
                editable
                onChangeText={handleChange("phone")}
                onBlur={handleBlur("phone")}
                style={global.textInput1}
                keyboardType="numeric"
                maxLength={15}
              />
            </View>
            <ErrorMessage errorValue={touched.phone && errors.phone} />
            <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
              <LargeButton
                title="Vazhdoni"
                // onPress={() => navigation.navigate("CodeVerification")}
                onPress={handleSubmit}
                disabled={!isValid || isSubmitting}
                loading={isSubmitting}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

I need to send this one value to the next screen  **phone: "+383" + value.phone** and Im trying to send it like this **navigation.navigate("CodeVerification",{phone});**

Its now working cause I cant navigate to the other screen, do you have any idea, thank you!!

Comment: What error do you get when calling `navigation.navigate("CodeVerification");` probably there is some problem with your stack configuration. This part of the code does not help to find your problem

Comment: Im not having error when calling ```navigation.navigate("CodeVerification");``` but when calling ```navigation.navigate("CodeVerification",{phone});```

Comment: :) what is the error then?  update your question with any error you get